# Server Administration versus Programming Tools

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, serverfault

In the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478218/how-to-set-up-a-new-user-account-in-sas), we have a question about configuring a tool that is a server tool (ie, a program that runs on a server and multiple users connect to), but is more closely associated with a programming tool, ie, SAS.  It seems to me that this is a question for Server Fault, but there has been some disagreement; and as I'm unsure of the precise point at which something goes from Stack Overflow to SF, I thought I'd ask here.

To me it seems sort of like a SQL Server question, which if it involves selecting or updating or joining something goes here, and if it involves installing SQL Server or administering users it would go on SF.

Answer (score 1):

it is not for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

From their help center on-topic list:

- Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software.
- Business/Enterprise grade virtualization
- Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
- Network routing, switches, and firewalls
- Operations, maintenance, and monitoring

SAS being a hihg-end datawarehouse/business intelligence tool it doesn't fit any of those topics.

Does that make the question on-topic for SO? I'm not sure. It is an edge case I guess which seems to be answerable by reading the SAS-manual but I'm sure community members with some rep in [sas](/questions/tagged/sas) will vote correctly.

Comment: SAS, however, is "Server ... software", among other things (which this is specifically asking as to), isn't it?

Comment: As to the edit, there aren't terribly many community members with rep in [tag:sas]; I'm the highest of the regular posters, and there are maybe 3 that post more than very occasionally with 3k+ rep.  Hence the question here.  :)

Comment: Do we stretch it that far? I only reckoned the software that was bundled with the operating system...and I was already once corected by a SF mod...I'm not going to given in lightly :-)

Comment: @Joe how many members over at SF will have the capability to answer? But you can judge if it is a 'simple' RTM thingy, isn't it?

Comment: I suppose my SQL Server comparison wasn't particularly apt since that would be a DBA question, wouldn't it.  Hmm.

Comment: Honestly, I'm shocked someone on SO was able to answer.  The job of 'SAS Programmer' is not particularly related to 'SAS Administrator', except in that it's a good promotion path - just like SQL Programmer -> DBA.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of .net membership as a comparison, if you have the AD version does it make it then off-topic for SO...